# eBay API request error: 'Invalid access token. Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header.'

Tags: ebay-api, bearer-token

- I've registered as a developer with eBay and created an app.
- I generated an Oauth (not Auth'n'Auth)
- Using Postman to generate a simple request (image) and recieving an error for token invalidity
- Error: `Invalid access token. Check the value of the Authorization HTTP request header.`

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

If your token is for "sandbox" environment, make sure you use sandbox API endpoints for your requests as well.

Instead of `https://api.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/...`,

try `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/buy/browse/v1/...`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues which might have happened is:

**The access token might have expired**

Use the refresh token to refresh the access token when it expires — you know when to do this when your call to the API returns a status code of `401` and the above body you saw in Postman.